# Next.js get static path name from files inside a folder

Tags: node.js, next.js

I'm trying to use `getStaticPaths` with extracted ids from JSON file names which are inside my public folder. My approach is as follows

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, "../../../../public/db/");
  var fileNames = [];
  fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log("Unable to scan directory: " + err);
    }
    files.forEach(function (file) {
      fileNames.push(file.substring( 0, file.indexOf(".")))
    });
  });

  console.log("fileNames",fileNames);

  return {
    fallback: false,
    paths: [
      {
        params: {
          reportId: "temp1",
        },
      },
      {
        params: {
          reportId: "temp2",
        },
      },
    ],
  };
}
```

I'm trying to push the file names into an array called `fileNames`. But I'm only seeing an empty array. I tried logging inside my `forEach` method and there I can clearly see my names. So my question is why is the push method not doing anything here?

Answer (score 3):

That's because the `readdir` callback is called asynchronously, and by the time you get to `console.log("fileNames", fileNames)` the `forEach` loop hasn't run yet.

I'd recommend using either the synchronous [`readdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/fs.html#fsreaddirsyncpath-options) version.

```js
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, "../../../../public/db/");
const fileNames = [];
const files = fs.readdirSync(directoryPath);
files.forEach(function (file) {
    fileNames.push(file.substring(0, file.indexOf(".")));
});

console.log("fileNames", fileNames);
```

Or, the promise-based [`readdir`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/fs.html#fspromisesreaddirpath-options) from `fs/promises`.

```js
import { readdir } from 'fs/promises';

const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, "../../../../public/db/");
const fileNames = [];
try {
    const files = await readdir(directoryPath);
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        fileNames.push(file.substring(0, file.indexOf(".")));
    });
    console.log("fileNames", fileNames);
} catch (err) {
    console.log("Unable to scan directory: " + err);
}
```